# mapping table as a reference for another table

Tags: sql-server, database, mapping, entity-relationship

I have two tables many to many, so i used mapping table for it

1st table: **course** that contains `course_id`, `course_name`, and `credit_hrs` attributes

2nd table: **y_term** that contains `yt_id`, `year`, and `term` attributes

mapping table is **y_t_course** that contains `yt_id` and `course_id` attributes

then i create a table, its name is **topic**, it is contains `cpt_id`, `topic_text`.

NOW i used `y_t_course` as a reference to `topic` table, it means has foreign key from `y_t_course`.

my question is how can i represent this relation in ER-Diagram

Answer (score 0):

I would use a tool like Visual Paradigm to get the ER diagrams required. Eclipse also has a plugin that does this.